# how to allow paging on gridview with custom databinding in place ?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, paging, checkboxlist

I am a bit lost in concept how to implement what i want to do.

I have a gridview, a checkboxlist. I bind the gridview on the page_load. Everytime user choose a checkboxlist, the gridview rebind as well. I have something like this now. This is not the actual code. Thanks so much.

aspx page.

```
    <asp:gridview allowpaging="true" pagesize="30" gridview>
```

aspx.vb page

```
    page_load

    get datatable from database
    gridview.datasource = datatable
    gridview.databind()

    Sub checkboxlist_selectedindexchange

    dim selected = checkboxlist.selecteditem.tostring()       
    Dim selecteddatatable =  datatable.select(columns() = selected).copytodatatable()

    Sub gridview_Pageindexchanging

    gridview.pageindex = e.newpageindex
    gridview_databind()

    Sub gridview_databind()

    ??????????
```

So what do i put here in order to allow paging ? basically, I have 2 datatables in the above example. In the actual code, I have about 5 datatables with 4 checkboxlists. I can't use Datasource control. I need to do it in codebehind as all code already exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your gridview_databind function should load the data again, like you did on the page_load event. Since you set the pageIndex on the datagrid in the gridview_PageIndexchanging event, it will know what page to show when you bind the data.

```
private sub gridview_databind()
    get datatable from database
    gridview.datasource = datatable
    gridview.databind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dave D, I can't really do that. I don't think you understand my question. There is one datatable on page_load and datatable changes after user make a selection using checkboxlists. I try to get current datatable using ... 

Dim datatable as datatable = TryCast(gridview1.datasource, datatable) but it just returns nothing all the time.

Comment: Unfortunately, your not going to be able to get the gridview1.datasource after a postback.

Comment: I found a way to do it by putting the datatables into SESSION STATES but i don't think it is a good way to do things. The datatables are hugh the whole datatable needs to rebind on page changing.

Comment: Here is a good article on efficient paging [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/07/434787.aspx).  It basically moves the paging to a stored procedure so you only get back the rows you need.

Comment: Thanks Dave D ... i will have a look through .. hope it helps